# Would you post to a math community blog at least once a month?

Tags: discussion, blog

Related to [SE site for "interesting mathematics"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8830/se-site-for-interesting-mathematics/8835)

I think we could set up a math blog

but to do so we would need some commitment.

> Would you post to a math community blog at least once a month?

Comment: Sure, why not.${}$

Comment: What is the target education level for this blog?

Comment: I would, I bet. And @anorton: I bet it would be whatever level you would be willing to write for :)

Comment: @anorton, I think would make sense to have MSE level. Anything that people from MSE might benefit from or enjoy.

Comment: Probably not. I barely manage to post on my own blog once a month.

Comment: I would contribute once every 6 months only. Due to my lack of proficiency in English the post might have some errors, although I would try my best.

Comment: Every month? No. Most months? Yes, I'm pretty sure I could and would.

Comment: I would love to help out, having been meaning to start one of my own for a while now (up to having a few half finished posts already written) however if I were to contribute I would still like to post the same things to my own personal blog.
What are people's opinions on this topic? If such a group blog were set up would we want the material to be "exclusive" so to speak, this would be a little bit of a turn off for me, but not a huge issue.

Comment: Half the reason I don't have a blog is because I don't think anybody would read it.  This would help with that.

Comment: I would probably only be able to write something fairly sporadically. I do have an idea for a series of posts, however, which would be a bit of an experiment and would require that at least a few people actually read the posts (so starting my own blog would not work for those).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 24):

I, for one, probably couldn't contribute something meaningful/interesting every month.

However, I could probably post an entry maybe once every two months, and certainly once every 3 months.  I'm sure there are plenty of users in my position, and enough of us could probably count as one person who'd contribute once a month.

If you're in the same position as I am, please upvote this post (so we get a feeling for the number of people in this category).

Answer (score 13):

Many of my top questions would be make better community blog posts than questions, especially [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/206890/12952) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/251955/12952).  I could see questions like these evolving into "community projects," with several writers posting replies to each other, working towards a larger problem.  I'd probably post there all the time.

Comment: Good idea. This is what security.stackexchange does and it works very well

Answer (score 2):

I probably would after a time.
I am old, and ready for a second career. I'd like to teach math at grade 8-10 level, so right up to Calculus I. (Currently prepping for my state's proficiency exam) I've been lurking and find math.SE interesting. If this blog comes to be, I'd see what's popular and would probably be able to produce content, after the intro period.

Answer (score 1):

for those of us who speak french, there is the wonderful http://images.math.cnrs.fr/